# Finding new software, checking their security history?

Tags: web-application, appsec, databases

I work for a company and we are looking to sign up for a new database/check-in software. As such we have gone through many different software, ranging from basic to very intricate web technologies.

My question is: is there a way to check the company's or the software's history to see if they have been hacked or their data has been breached in the past?

Aside from simply asking them, I have found that it is easy for them to dismiss the issue as we have been solely speaking with the sales/project managers and have had a hard time getting in contact with anyone that's not blowing bubbles.

Comment: *have had a hard time getting in contact with anyone that's not blowing bubbles* this by itself is already a red flag.

Answer (score 2):

Check if they have a "security" page describing how they want vulnerabilities to be reported to them. If they are open to responsible disclosure there's a good chance they do security the right way, and it would give you some confidence that should a vulnerability be disclosed they'll quickly fix it.

Also take a look to see if they have any open source code published, if so you could have a read through it and possibly see whether the code conforms to good standards or is an bug-prone mess that can have exploits. It isn't guaranteed, but there's a good chance that if their open-source code is awful, so is their proprietary code you would be using.

Finally see what kind of company they are - are they legitimately making great products and earning money from that, or do they sell outdated, non-interoperable and bug-prone crap on purpose so you have to pay them for consulting? I would immediately run away from [such a company](https://www.oracle.com).

A bit unrelated to security but I'd like to add anyway - a lot of enterprise/accounting/etc software is marketed to appeal to the people in charge of buying it (you) by an overdose of buzz-words instead of the people who will actually use it. Try to get a demo of their software, give it to the people who will actually use it (your accountants, etc) and see what *they* think about it. I've seen way too many apps that looked great on paper and management was all excited about it, but the user experience was so poor the software wasn't even worth a cent if you actually wanted to be productive with it.

Comment: Oh, snap! That's a burn.

Comment: One might say you ["burned"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burn&defid=8998) Oracle.

Comment: its funny you mention oracle, as they were a company that actually reached out to me to get more information in our facility to see if they had a software that would be a good fit. I was told they would be in contact again with me by end of day after our "demo". Its been a month now.

Comment: So I looked into the security they provide and it seems as though the only things listed are : PCI Security Scanning and Security Verified Requirements. My question is how good of a security verification process is this? Common sense tells me that it would be pretty in depth to prevent access to databases that hold credit card information.

Comment: @BrettReinhard out of curiosity, did their solution pass the user experience test (as opposed to "impress the boss with buzzwords" test)? PCI is quite easy to pass for a large enough company and there's a lot of stuff that isn't covered by it and yet still important. Also, you can pass PCI by having the card-related infrastructure (relatively) secure while the rest is crap. As I said see if they have a responsible disclosure page (or ask them how they handle vulnerabilities) and judge by their response. Buzzword-filled boilerplate BS means run away.

Comment: @BrettReinhard finally you may just consider hiring a small company to make you a bespoke solution in a sane and modern language, that you can then maintain in-house if needed by hiring developers. No vendor lock-in, no salespeople, no BS, and working in a small company means they're more likely to ask a fair price for the amount of work instead of trying to milk you out up to the last cent like the big players do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but you could check if their software has a good or bad record in terms of vulnerabilities. Just google for software name and then "exploit" or "vulnerability". If something exists, you'll be directed to links of corresponding CVEs or links on exploit DB or similar.

Comment: Thank you, this advice seems pretty basic but it's always good to have little reminders. This is something that completely escaped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching the [NIST National Vulnerability Database](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-advanced) for your vendor and its products. Even if the exact software you are considering is not found, perhaps seeing CVE for the vendor's other products may be insightful. Are the CVE nearly all reported by third parties or does the vendor report many of them? The latter is a sign that the firm takes security more seriously than most.

Look at their security pages for a bug bounty program. An increasing number of vendors are offering these programs to widen the net for software vulnerabilities.  The existence of such a program is a positive indicator that the firm is serious about offering more secure software. To promote such programs,[HackerOne](https://hackerone.com/about) was created by security leaders from Facebook, Microsoft and Google. HackerOne provides vulnerability coordination and bug bounty platform.

As implied by @andreborie quality and security are highly correlated. If the code is poorly written, it will be difficult to secure.

Your contract language should include incentives for software to adhere to higher coding and assurance standards and levy consequences for egregious violations of those standards. The criteria for best value (vs lowest cost, or highest technical) should include requirements for [software assurance](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/swa) (not to be confused with the Microsoft marketing program). Software companies who perform well (or not) to these criteria should be accorded due weight in proposal and past-performance evaluations.

For an example of a robust set of such criteria, see [Appropriate Software Security Control Types for Third Party Service and Product Providers](https://www.fsisac.com/sites/default/files/news/Appropriate%20Software%20Security%20Control%20Types%20for%20Third%20Party%20Service%20and%20Product%20Providers.pdf), by the FS-ISAC Third Party Software Security Working Group Version 2.3 / October, 2015. Leading software and financial industry leaders contributed to this excellent document. The FS-ISAC is the most credible, current and complete reference I am aware of.

Many software assurance tools include clauses that prohibit the user from publishing any comparison with other tools. Such restrictions on research slows technical improvements and makes it very difficult for buyers to conduct informed market research and comparative assessment to determine which tool or tools are most beneficial for them. Contract language should permit purchasers of a tool to publish comparisons.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for, in addition to the other answers I feel as though I have a good platform to move forward.

Comment: Don't forget to up vote the helpful answers, as that is the major incentive for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the security history of a product, you can search the product from https://www.exploit-db.com 
There may be some code execution or injection vulnerabilities, if there are a lot of them, you can evaluate easily.